# Would optical signal processing still suffer from slew rate?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electric-circuits, signal-processing, non-linear-optics

In electronics, analog signal processing/computation suffers from parasitic capacitance which leads to [slew rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slew_rate)—which is the maximum change of voltage allowed, so handling super-high frequency becomes impossible.

Is this still true for optical signal processing/computation, such as optical (frequency) mixer or optical frequency multiplier? If so, what would be the physics behind?

Answer (score 0):

Your question includes both the *conversion* (since you speak of *processing*) and light propagation. Conversion involves electronics, as @Nasha mentions, and thus *is* directly impacted by the slew rate.

Light propagation speed is reduced (with respect to that in vacuum) by the refractive index of the material. The physics causing the finite slew rate is also also causing the fact that the refractive index of the material is always greater than 1.

Comment: OK. Let us forget about processing. Let me stick to optical mixer and/or optical frequency multipliers. I do not think they necessarily involve electronics, if the original signal is already optical. In such a case, would there be slew rate issues? According to your answer, it seems that only light propagation speed problem exists..

Comment: I am raising this question, because it is often said that optical signal processing allows for frequencies higher than allowed by electronics signal processing. Even adding and multiplying signals, which may count as processing or not, is affected by slew rate in electronics domain. Thus my question.

Comment: @MBK, Light propagation is involved as long as you are in optical domain: unlike electroncs, photons cannot be stationary. Hence the same logic applies to 'any' light-related process: you will always have light in some material, this material will consist of atoms, refractive index will be greater than 1.